# Socket function not firing on server end using Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm an average JavaScripter who's just started to learn how to use sockets via Node JS. My code runs fine, and the client connects to the server with no problem, but I just can't seem to get the server code to fire when I emit from the client. I get no errors on the console from the server end, or errors in the developer tools from the client. The debugger shows the command getting sent out fine from the client, but it just doesn't seem to want to fire on the server end. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

CLIENT:

```html
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"> 

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1111/SystemAlpha.html');

SendData("NewPlayer");

function SendData(A) {

 if (A == "NewPlayer") { socket.emit('NewPlayer', {Map:System, Direction:Ship[1], Speed:Ship[2], X:Ship[4], Y:Ship[5] } ); }
}
```

SERVER:

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var socket = require('socket.io');

var server = app.listen(1111, function() { console.log('Server Listening'); } );

app.use(express.static('htdocs'));

var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

 socket.onerror = function(error){ console.log('Error detected: ' + error); }

 console.log('Client Connected');

 socket.on('NewPlayer', function(data) { console.log('Recieved'); });


});
```

I get the "Client Connected" message, but the "Received" message never comes through to the console.

*EDITED

So after an exhausted search for 2 days as to what the problem is, I have not been able to find a single solution.  I have found others who have had the same issue who cannot emit from their client to the server. For the most part, it seems to work for most people, but a small handful can't make it work even though their code is fine. I have checked the network tab in developer tools, and it does not show any requests being sent to the server, so I'm assuming the bug is on the client side somewhere.  I double checked to see if node.js has access through the firewall, and it does on both public and private networks. I disabled the firewall anyway and tested it, but still no response from the server.  I changed the code and put the function into a clickable event in case the call was being handled too quickly before the connection was established, but this did nothing as well.  I changed the emit command to a send command instead to see if that made a difference, but it doesn't.  The solution is a stumper.  I'm writing this code on Windows 10 and I've tested it in both Edge and Chrome, and the result is still the same......

Comment: We need to see a more complete version of the relevant client code including the part where the client connects.

Comment: @jfriend00. Ok. Thanks. This is the gist of the scripts. I've updated the snippets above.

Comment: In that client-side code you show, it doesn't look like you're waiting for the connection to finish before trying to send data on that connection.

Comment: @jfriend00. I already tried that. I moved the function into a click event and waited for the connection to be established first.  It still didn't fire on the server no matter how long I waited before clicking. I'll keep on tinkering with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bunch of tinkering, I finally got it to work.  I'm not sure why, but I think I may have installed Express in Node JS without making it a dependency. (npm install express --save). I'm not an expert in Node JS, so I can't confirm that this was the issue. I would assume that the connection would fail from the start if I didn't do that, but then again maybe not.  It's the only thing I can think of that I may have done wrong, but it all works now, so if you stumble across this page having the same issue, try re-installing Express (if you're using Express) with the --save extension to make it a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem in client code. Connect to server is async as well.

socket.on("connect" ,  function () {SendData("NewPlayer");})